# Matlab cdfplof do not show complete graph when multiple cdfs are plotted in one graph with x-axis as log scale

Tags: matlab, plot, cdf

I am trying to use `cdfplot()` to plot multiple sets of data in one graph. When I use the normal x-axis, everything is fine. However, when I try to change the x-axis to log scale, the cdf plot of some sets of data do not display complete.

I have two sets of data: `setFive` and `setSeven`. I want to plot cdf of them in the same graph, with x-axis being log scale.

Here are the two graphs, one is in normal x-axis, the other is in log scale x-axis. The cdf of "five" in log scale x-axis does not go to 0.

[image: Normal X-axis]

[image: Log scale X-axis]

The two sets of data are:

> setSeven=[ 0.1478
>       0.2493
>       0.0650
>       0.1808
>       0.3633
>       0.1684
>       0.3116
>       0.1398
>            0
>            0
>       0.3069
>       0.3252
>       0.1762
>       0.4192
>            0
>       0.1163
>            0
>            0
>       0.2338
>            0
>       0.1388
>            0
>       0.2420
>       0.1115
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.1530
>       0.1675
>       0.3333
>            0
>            0
>       0.2351
>       0.1555
>            0
>            0
>       0.1691
>       0.2042
>       0.3143
>            0
>            0
>       0.2206
>            0
>       0.2288
>       0.1271
>            0
>       0.1852
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.1226
>            0
>            0
>       0.1571
>       0.1807
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.3231
>       0.1358
>       0.1681
>            0
>       0.1924
>       0.1494
>       0.1474
>       0.1030
>       0.2008
>       0.1455
>            0
>       0.2351
>       0.2537
>            0
>       0.1353
>            0
>       0.1320
>       0.1675
>       0.1844
>            0
>            0
>       0.2691
>       0.3640
>            0
>            0
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.2395
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.3156
>       0.2007
>       0.4463
>            0
>            0
>       0.2526
>       0.2375
>       0.3521
>       0.2279
>            0];
>
> setFive=[0.1476
>               0.3300
>               0.0940
>               0.2704
>               0.3659
>               0.2214
>               0.3658
>               0.1402
>               0.2295
>               0.2105
>               0.3324
>               0.4011
>               0.2823
>               0.5740
>               0.2916
>               0.1940
>               0.2559
>               0
>               0.2423
>               0.1734
>               0.1992
>               0
>               0.2822
>               0.4122
>               0.2312
>               0
>               0.2598
>               0.3808
>               0.5833
>               0.6131
>               0
>               0.2831
>               0.6418
>       0.2269
>       0.2532
>       0.1944
>       0.3515
>       0.2734
>       0.3908
>       0.3223
>            0
>       0.3303
>            0
>       0.2759
>       0.2144
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.1747
>       0.2721
>       0.2509
>       0.2542
>            0
>       0.1381
>       0.2562
>       0.1918
>       0.2243
>       0.2260
>       0.3823
>       0.2404
>       0.3963
>       0.2917
>       0.2390
>       0.2818
>       0.2863
>       0.2366
>       0.2289
>            0
>       0.1183
>       0.2660
>       0.2535
>       0.1917
>       0.1976
>            0
>            0
>            0
>            0
>       0.4433
>            0
>       0.3395
>       0.4199
>       0.3674
>            0
>            0
>       0.2814
>            0
>       0.3816
>       0.4754
>       0.3198
>       0.4995
>       0.5585
>       0.2965
>       0.5316
>       0.4914
>       0.6343
>       0.4036
>       0.3632
>       0.4205
>       0.3089
>       0.4521];

Here are the codes:

```
e=cdfplot(setFive);
set(e,'LineStyle','-','color','k');
hold on;

g=cdfplot(setSeven);
set(g,'LineStyle','--','color','k');
hold on; 

set(gca,'Xscale','log');
axis([0 1 0 1]);
get(gca,'xlim')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the processing the function `cdfplot` makes on the input, coupled with the logarithmic representation.

Consider the `setSeven` input data set (the same applies to `setFive`): the first 5 points generated by `cdfplot` are:

```
x7= -Inf         0         0    0.0650    0.0650
y7=    0         0    0.4300    0.4300    0.4400
```

You canget these points using the `get` function wiht the handles returned by `cdfplot`:

```
x5=get(e,'xdata');
y5=get(e,'ydata');
x7=get(g,'xdata');
y7=get(g,'ydata');
```

where:

- x5: x data from `setFive` data set
- y5: y data from `setFive` data set
- x7: x data from `setSeven` data set
- x7: y data from `setSeven` data set

In the first of your graph, you see the line starting from `x=0, y=0` then climbing to `x=0, y=0.43`.

In this graph actually the first point `x=-inf, y=0` is missing since the plot function simply ignores values such as `-inf, inf, NaN`.

Something similar happens when you set the `xaxis` scale as `logarithmic`:

In this case, the first 3 point are ignored, since

```
log10([-Inf 0 0 0.0650 0.0650]) is [ Inf + 1.3644i -Inf -Inf -1.1871 -1.1871]
```

so, the first two point displayable on the graph are the fourth and the fifth which correspond to:

```
x=0.0650, y=0.4300
x=0.0650, y=0.4400
```

the first three point are then ignored.

As said at the beginning, this also happens for the `setFive` data set.

In this case you have:

```
x5= -Inf        0         0    0.0940    0.0940
y5=   0         0    0.1900    0.1900    0.2000
```

So in the first graph the first point is not diplayed and since

```
log10([ -Inf   0   0 0.0940  0.0940]) is  Inf + 1.3644i   -Inf -Inf  -1.0269    -1.0269
```

the first three point will not be displayed in the second graph (log scale).

In conlcusion, you are right, some points are not diplayed in both the graphs but this is correct given the set of data to be displayed and the function you are using.

You can find below the two graphs zoomed to highlight the first point plotted (`setFive` in red, `setSeven` in black).

**Zoom of the graph with xaxis linear scale**
[image]

**Zoom of the graph with xaxis logarithmic scale**
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. Now I understand that log-scale treat 0 as -inf so it omits the part of graph. Your answer includes very concise example and code, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it does exactly what it should do.

The cdf tries to generate a function that mimics the population distribution from the sample you gave it. 
As a tule of thumb I prefer using the plot function, as it gives you more power and you are in complete control of the data. 
So if you consider the below code and the figure it creates, it just means that in log space (where log(0) = -inf) you cannot plot any value of zero. 
Therefore, only values that differ from zeros are viable, and the rest are omitted from the plot.

now if you find out these in the two data sets, using the following line

```
[min(cx5(cx5>0)),min(cx7(cx7>0))]
```

you will see that set five minimal value is much larger than set seven.
Now think on what is the log spacing when max is one, it emphasizes differences that are closer to zero on the expense of differences that are closer to one.

But as far as cdf's go these results are impressive.

Enjoy.

```
[cy5,cx5] = ecdf(setFive);
[cy7,cx7] = ecdf(setSeven);
subplot(221)
plot(cx5,cy5,'LineStyle','-','color','k');hold on
plot(cx7,cy7,'LineStyle','--','color','k');hold off
ylabel('F(x)'); xlabel('x');title('Empirical CDF');
axis([0 1 0 1])
subplot(222)
plot(cx5,cy5,'LineStyle','-','color','k');hold on
plot(cx7,cy7,'LineStyle','--','color','k');hold off
ylabel('F(x)'); xlabel('x');title('Empirical CDF');
set(gca,'Yscale','log');
axis([0 1 0 1]) 
subplot(223)
plot(cx5,cy5,'LineStyle','-','color','k');hold on
plot(cx7,cy7,'LineStyle','--','color','k');hold off
ylabel('F(x)'); xlabel('x');title('Empirical CDF');
set(gca,'Xscale','log');
axis([0 1 0 1])
subplot(224)
plot(cx5,cy5,'LineStyle','-','color','k');hold on
plot(cx7,cy7,'LineStyle','--','color','k');hold off
ylabel('F(x)'); xlabel('x');title('Empirical CDF');
set(gca,'Xscale','log','Yscale','log');
axis([0 1 0 1])
```

[image: the different options you can plot]

Comment: Thanks for your plots! I really appreciate the comparison between these graphs, it is very clear! I have one follow-up question and I really appreciate if you can help me with it. The reason that I wanted to use log-scale x-axis is that, I have more sets of data and the cdf of them range from [0 10] in x-axis, but are crowded in the x-interval [0 1].So I wanted to enlarge this interval by using log-scale..However, I do need to show what is the percentage of "0" in the data set. So is there anyway I can plot multiple cdf graphs with uneven x-axis? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: you need to start a new question with the example data